# Titanium Module (is there any module or support of App dynamics for titanium appcelrator)

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules, titanium-sdk

We have Some question Related about app dynamics module in Appcelerator.

1. How to use the iOS  libraries  in the appcelerator module which supports the framework of appdynmics.  Is it possible to add a iOS native library in appcelerator titanium ?
2. Is there any support for appdynmics in appcelerator Titanium ?
3. Is there any module for the appdynmics in appcelerator?

Answer (score 1):

**1.**: Yes, you can extend Titanium by creating modules or using Hyperloop. The best option currently is to create a module. Some documentation is available at:
* https://devblog.axway.com/mobile-apps/write-titanium-ios-native-modules-swift/
* https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/iOS+Module+Development+Guide

the 2nd link also has an Android section if you are interested in that too.
Appdynamics SDK documentation can be found here: https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO45/Instrument+iOS+Applications

**2. / 3.** No (at least not on github). There is a page at http://gitt.io/search?q=appdynamics where you can search for modules on github

So you can either create one yourself or make a offer in the Ti-Slack Job section (ti-slack.slack.com/). Perhaps you'll find someone who will create one for you.